# How to properly delete with AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I did some clean up in my S3 buckets and deleted S3 bucket with weird names. Now my CDK stacks are in weird states.
I have some CDK stacks running.

$`cdk ls` shows
LambdaHoroscrape

I destroy the stack with those commands

`cdk destroy`

`cdk destroy LambdaHoroscrape`

Are you sure you want to delete: LambdaHoroscrape (y/n)? y

LambdaHoroscrape: destroying...

LambdaHoroscrape: destroyed

---

However the stack LambdaHoroscrape is still present, `cdk ls` confirms it.

**How can I properly delete this CDK stack ?**

Context: I wanted to delete the stack because my deployment ( `cdk deploy` ) showed this cryptic message

> [%] fail: No bucket named 'cdktoolkit-stagingbucket-zd83596pa2cm'. Is account xxxxx bootstrapped?

I boostrapped my account with
`cdk bootstrap aws://{account_number}/{region}`

Others encountered this cryptic error as well
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6808

In the end, because of this error and eagerness to destroy the stack, I lost my DynamoDB data collected since 2 weeks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The message is caused by the fact that you deleted the CDK asset bucket created during bootstrapping. You'll need to re-bootstrap your environment to deploy there.

As for deleting, CDK deploys cloudformation stacks, so a sure way to delete something is to go to the cloudformation console and delete the stack.

Regarding the stacks still showing up in `cdk ls` after destroying - this is working as expected. `cdk destroy` does not remove your CDK code that defines the stack. `cdk ls` outputs the stacks that are defined by your CDK code and are present in the synthesized CloudFormation template, regardless of whether they're deployed or not.

Comment: Deleting the stack on CloudFormation did the trick. I can deploy again.